# How to access main window's methods that changes UI elements from another object?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm working on a simple network game (tictactoe).
There's a `MainWindow` class that contains few user controls (`Canvas`, `TextBox`, few `Labels` etc).
[image]

The `MainWindow` class contains an object of class `ClientTCP` (made by myself) that runs a new thread that listens to a server. If the `ClientTCP` object gets a new packet from the server, some action should be taken.

Let's say "PacketYouHaveWon" arrived to `ClientTCP`. I want then `ClientTCP` to write on `MainWindow's` console "hehe".

I've managed this to work by doing something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      writeInConsole += writeInConsole2;
}
public static Delegate1 writeInConsole;
public delegate void Delegate1(string str1);        
private void writeInConsole2(string txt)
{
      textBoxConsole.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxConsole.AppendText(txt + "\n")));
}
```

And in `ClientTCP`, when I receive such a packet, I'm just calling

```
Game.writeInConsole("hehe");
```

Is this approach allright? I'd like to know whether there are any other (maybe better?) ways to do that.

Comment: Use `Action<T>` instead of creating a delegate type.

Comment: but Action<T> requires writeInConsole2 method to be static, and if I make that method static, I cann't access UI controls from there

Comment: As for me it's to difficult, why you can't make writeInConsole2 method public and call it when you need write to console, delegate is not needed

Comment: Sorry, I realized that misunderstood the question. Better way to do what you want is to implement event in ClientTCP class and subscribe for that event in MainWindow, in handler of event you can call your writeInConsole2 method. String "hehe" you should pack into event args

Comment: could u support me with some example?